# Why is my question closed and how can I improve it?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[This](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/71097/is-java-really-multiplatform-for-games?noredirect=1#comment128483_71097) is a question I asked today that has been closed as off-topic. I edited it to make it more on topic and am told is still off topic but for a different reason.

I honestly do not understand what is wrong with my question. How can a question about hardware supported by Java be subjective, it either supports it or it doesn't?

Can someone explain what I have done wrong and how to better phrase my question to get them answered instead of closed.

Answer (score 5):

There are two aspects of your question that make it off-topic here (emphasis in all quotes is mine):

> With all the devices that are used for gaming now **is java a good
>   choice for games** on the merit of its cross platform compatibility or
>   is there no benefit in changing from c++.

"Is *X* a good choice?" is a form of "which technology should I use?" and such questions are outside the scope of the site (see the [Help Center](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help)). They are extremely broad, discussion-focused questions, and this is not a discussion forum.

> What i am interested in is **if i start my next game in java will i be
>   able to target a larger audience than if i did it in C++** as java is
>   "cross platform" out of the box but does that apply to games.

"If I do *X*, will I have a larger audience?" isn't something that can be easily supported by facts and objective data, in many cases. Sure, there are some, but this isn't one of them. Support for C++ and for Java on modern platforms in just about ubiquitous, but there is no concrete way to say what the "available audience" is for a program written in either (especially since the audience for your game, *players*, rarely care about the technology used to build a game). As such this is just going to result in discussion fostered mainly by opinions (of which there are many, and they can be polarizing).

Fundamentally you are still asking "what should I choose, Java or C++," though, even with your edit. So the question is still off-topic.

Further, you *did not ask about hardware* as your meta question asserts. In fact the word "hardware" appears nowhere in the question as of this post (and a question about what hardware Java is supported on wouldn't be on-topic here either).

---

I'm not sure how to tell you what to do to improve this question, as fundamentally what you want to know seems to be "C++ or Java?" That's not a topic we want to host on this site.

That said, I left you a comment on the question with my advice.

Comment: +1 for "especially since the audience for your game, players, rarely care about the technology used to build a game"  the one exception there is Linux users, which tells you a lot about Linux